# How to deactivate "Autodesk.VisualClusters" extension before unloading?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am using the viewer.loadExtension and viewer.unloadExtension functions to load and unload the "Autodesk.VisualClusters" extension. But if the user has already activated the extension then unloading it directly causes some residual data to remain in the viewer.

[residual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MVi6.png)

How do I call the VisualClusters deactivate function? I tried getExtension() and then calling deactivate but it dosen't seem to be working.

`props.viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.VisualClusters").setActive();`
`let unloadval = props.viewer.unloadExtension("Autodesk.VisualClusters");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the layout of the extension like so:

```js
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.VisualClusters').reset();
```

After that you can unload the extension as usual.

Comment: However similarly if I want to activate the extension upon loading it, how do I achieve that through code? So far what I have tried is viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.VisualClusters').setActive(true) but that didn't work.

Comment: There's a method on the extension called `setLayoutActive(bool)`. If you call it with `true` as the parameter, it'll activate the clustered layout.

Comment: Where can I found an online resource of all the methods and properties of Autodesk.VisualClusters